# Builtin Filter Algorithm

Tags: filtering

In 25.1 there is (still) no builtin algorithm named `filter`. Why? What should I use instead? I think I've read somewhere that a standardized filter algorithm should be added to Emacs.

Comment: Please edit your post to explain what you want `filter` to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My crystal ball tells me that you want

```
(require 'seq)
```

and then

```
... (seq-filter ...) ...
```

The `seq` package is built-in, even though you have to say explicitly when you want to use it.  Of course it's still not called `filter`, you may say, so you additionally need

```
(defalias 'filter #'seq-filter)
```

tho I'd advise against doing that.

Answer (score 3):

Does it need to be "named `filter`"?

As @Stefan mentions, `seq-filter` is available in Emacs 25.1.

Earlier releases, going back to almost forever, have functions `remove-if` and `remove-if-not`, in library `cl.el`. Recent releases provide the same functions under the names `cl-remove-if` and `cl-remove-if-not`, in library `cl-seq.el` (so you need not load library `cl.el` at runtime, to get them).

All of these do essentially the same thing, and probably the same thing as what you are requesting (whose behavior is not really specified). You can of course name any of them "`filter`" using `defalias`, if you want.

Comment: I just wanted to give almost the same answer. You beat me;-).